# Django REST API allows post from Swagger, but not from postman or vue form using axios

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model that I can add records to with the Admin interface or Swagger POST.  However I have a vue form that gives a code 400 with nothing else in explanation.  I tried to use postman but it gives `"detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."`

Here is the JSON used in SWAGGER.

```
{
    "matchingKey": "chgpt-a",
    "sequence": 1515,
    "param_kwargs_json": {},
    "param1": "tensorFlow",
    "param2": "N/A",
    "param3": "N/A",
    "param4": "N/A",
    "param5": "N/A",
    "param6": "N/A",
    "param7": "N/A",
    "param8": "N/A",
    "param9": "N/A",
    "param10": "N/A",
    "description": "test from postman 1331"
}
```

here are the response headers from SWAGGER

```
access-control-allow-origin: * 
 allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS 
 content-length: 265 
 content-type: application/json 
 cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin 
 date: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 06:27:13 GMT 
 referrer-policy: same-origin 
 server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.9 
 vary: Accept, Origin, Cookie 
 x-content-type-options: nosniff 
 x-frame-options: DENY
```

When I use the exact same JSON in Postman with the following headers...

```
request_headers= {'Content-Length': '222', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'localhost:8000', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"', 'Origin': 'http://localhost:444', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Referer': 'http://localhost:444/', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}
```

I have my settings for CORS as follows:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:8000", "http://localhost:444/"]
#CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
    'http://localhost:5173',
    'http://127.0.0.1:444',
    'http://localhost:444'
]
```

My vue form submit method is as follows:

```
aveParameter(_newParameters){
        console.log('saveParameter()')
        this.swalLoading('Adding New Parameter...')
        //check for completeness
        if(true){
            console.log('saveParameter data = %s', _newParameters.matchingKey)
            setTimeout(()=>{
            // POST API FOR ADDING Parameter
            getAPI.post('http://localhost:8000/api/parameters/', _newParameters)
            .then(res=>{

                // SETS MESSAGE FOR RESPONSE
                let message = `Parameter ${res.data.requestpath} ${res.data.requestmethod} has been successfully added.`

                // DISPLAYS SUCCESS SCREEN/MODAL
                this.swalSuccess(message)

            })
            .catch(err=>{
                this.swalError(err)
            })
        }, 1000)
        }
```

The Console.log when I try to post is as follows:

```
oggleAddParameterModal
mixins.js:130 --mixins toggleModal(addParameter)
mixins.js:139 Proxy(Object) {closeModal: ƒ, …}
ParametersTableModal.vue?t=1680847383434:119 saveParameter()
ParametersTableModal.vue?t=1680847383434:123 saveParameter data = moogoogaipan
mixins.js:130 --mixins toggleModal(addParameter)
mixins.js:139 Proxy(Object) {closeModal: ƒ, …}
xhr.js:187          POST http://localhost:8000/api/parameters/ 400 (Bad Request)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:187
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:53
request @ Axios.js:108
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:140
wrap @ bind.js:9
(anonymous) @ ParametersTableModal.vue?t=1680847383434:126
setTimeout (async)
saveParameter @ ParametersTableModal.vue?t=1680847383434:124
(anonymous) @ ParametersTableModal.vue:111
(anonymous) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1450
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:339
mixins.js:130 --mixins toggleModal(parametersTable)
mixins.js:139 Proxy(Object) {validate: ƒ, formatPrice: ƒ, formatPriceIntl: ƒ, …}
```

The JSON is virtually the same from all inputs with swagger having pretty json with \n every so often, but other than that the same, and that's the one that is working.

I suspect CORS but with the settings I have, CORS should NOT be a player.  The other hint comes from the media type text/plain, but none of the headers have anything but application/json seems uniform.

I have other vue.js forms that are working on that same application, so I am at a loss, maybe a fresh set of eyes can help me find the mistake.

AV

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the model not the gui.

Here is the correct row in the model:

```
param2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null = True, default = 'N/A' )
```

in the other models that were working, I had both blank and null set to `True` like here, when I updated the offending model to add `blank=True`, everything was back to normal, the error messages were misleading.